# What bonuses (if any) apply to the additional damage inflicted by Two-Weapon Rend?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

When you successfully make an attack with Two-Weapon Rend what kind of bonuses are you allowed to add to this damage? For instance can you apply the bonus from Power Attack or the damage bonus from Inspire Courage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> you deal an additional 1d10 points of damage plus 1-1/2 times your Strength modifier

The word “additional” here makes it clear to me that this is bonus damage, added on to the damage you are already doing, and therefore not a separate instance of damage. It is thus very unlikely that you’ll ever see any bonus that adds to it—something that increases every damage bonus you have would be nonsensical, so you’d need something that explicitly increases the damage dealt by Two-Weapon Rend. Power Attack and inspire courage definitely do not increase it—those are separate bonuses also added to whatever damage you were already doing, just like Two-Weapon Rend is.

Unlike damage *bonuses*, though, damage *multipliers* should apply to Two-Weapon Rend. They won’t improve the 1dd10—bonus damage dice are never multiplied—but they will improve the 1½×Str bonus damage.

Which leads us to the really big problem: if Two-Weapon Rend applies a bonus to a damage roll, *which damage roll does it apply to?* Triggering Two-Weapon Rend requires hitting at least twice, which leads to two separate damage rolls. This is not clear, however, I think the most reasonable reading here is that it applies to every roll—but you can only actually get it once, so once you apply it to a roll it doesn’t apply to the rest. You presumably get to choose which one. This is potentially useful, because if you attack many times and one of those attacks is a critical hit, you can choose to apply your Two-Weapon Rend bonus damage to that attack, and thus multiply part of it.

Comment: I don't buy your reading of when it's applied; it seems to be triggered the moment you land an attack with your main or off-hand after you've hit with the other, and would apply to *that* damage. My understanding of a Full Attack action is that you make each attack, starting with the highest bonus and going down, in sequential order, applying each effect as you go (it may be common to roll all of your attacks rapidly to save time, but I don't believe that is how it works mechanically)

Comment: @Ifusaso Sadly, you’re probably right. Probably just wishful thinking on my part that this feat would be anything but a trap.

Comment: Eh it's more random but about comparable to Weapon Specialization. It's not Power Attack, but if you want more damage, it's functional. Definitely not the best Feat choice, but if you have extra Feats using two weapons, you're probably a Fighter anyway and it's fine as a choice when you have that many Feat slots.

Comment: @Ifusaso Weapon Specialization is not functional. There is near-literally no reason anyone should ever take that feat at all.

Comment: Well in my experience it's the Feat that is used to gauge damage feats. Different play groups, I guess